# Why hasn't anyone won Fanatic yet?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, badges

I recently got W00T (Enthusiast) and am now looking to Fanatic.  I saw on another post that SO has been open for 11 months but no one has won Fanatic yet.  Is it broken or just a coincidence?

Comment: A better question is why wasn't it made retroactive?

Comment: Yup, I agree - why should days before the badges introduction be worth any less than days after?  If anything, being an early adopter of SO would make you more of a fanatic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Fanatic badge was just unveiled and started tracking [around 6/26/09](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/). It'll be September before anybody gets it.

Comment: That would explain it, I must have joined and started visiting days after they were unveiled.

Answer (score 6):

Today's the day.

Front page is stacked with them.

[alt text http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/4804/fanaticbadge.png](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/4804/fanaticbadge.png)

Comment: Awwwwwwwwwwwwwwww hell yeah, just got mine.

Comment: Me too. I have the flair enabled on my blog, and I saw a gold on it. I was confused until I came to SO. Now I'm proud. :)

Comment: hooray for the i-have-no-life badge. my 1st gold

Comment: Wohoo, got mine today! First gold on SO, second gold overall. Now that I think about it---why do I even care? Cursing you, Jeff Atwood, you and your stupid addictive ideas...

Answer (score 3):

Enthusiast and Fanatic was recently added badges. And the time period started after they have been added.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the count for the Fanatic badge started at the same time as the Woot! badge, I would expect the first round to be awarded on or around September 4th.

Comment: September 4th UTC! Who called it? (I did)

Answer (score 0):

Ding Fanatic!  (It's an mmo thing)